# When are default values of nested models instantiated?

Tags: python, pydantic

I have a complex configuration tree hierarchy, with pydantic Models nested several layers deep and I noticed a strange behaviour I cannot really explain.

Let's take this [example based on the documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/#validate-always):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep

class DemoModel(BaseModel):
    ts: datetime = None

    @validator('ts', pre=True, always=True)
    def set_ts_now(cls, v):
        return v or datetime.now()

    def __init__(self, **data):
        super().__init__(**data)
        print('Creating new DemoModel with ts =', self.ts)
```

This works as expected:

```
d1 = DemoModel()
sleep(1)
d2 = DemoModel()

assert d1.ts < d2.ts
```

Now when I nest this into a [recursive model](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#recursive-models) with a default value like this:

```
class CompositeModel(BaseModel):
    demo: DemoModel = DemoModel()
```

Then `DemoModel` only gets instantiated once when the `CompositeModel` class is defined.
Therefore:

```py
c1 = CompositeModel()
sleep(1)
c2 = CompositeModel()

assert c1 == c2
```

This is a bit unexpected and I haven't seen it mentioned in the documentation, but it makes some sense as we're dealing with class variables which in normal python are instantiated per class and not per object.

However, wouldn't therefore `c1.demo` and `c2.demo` be the same object? Thus if I change one I would expect the "other" to change too, but this is not the case:

```py
c1.demo.ts = datetime(2042,1,1)
assert c1.demo.ts == c2.demo.ts # fails!
```

So clearly they are different instances. But the constructor (`__init__`) was only called once! *What is going on here?*

---

If I define the composite model with a validator that dynamically instantiates the sub-model I get the original behaviour back, where every instance of the parent also gets a fresh instance of the child:

```py
class CompositeModel2(BaseModel):
    demo: DemoModel = None

    @validator('demo', pre=True, always=True)
    def set_demo_dynamically(cls, v):
        return v or DemoModel()
```

Maybe using a [`Field` with a `dynamic_factory`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#field-with-dynamic-default-value) would be another way to get this behaviour?

Comment: *Syntactically*, `t1` looks like a class attribute. The metaclass, though, uses it to define code that creates an *instance* attribute that shadows (if it doesn't remove altogether) the class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your `c1` is a copy of `c2` which means that they are neither the same object nor is `c2.demo` instantiated. Just copied. If you want to avoid this, don't use mutable default values such as your `DemoModel`.

From the docs:

> A common source of bugs in python is to use a mutable object as a default value for a function or method argument, as the same instance ends up being reused in each call. [...]
> Pydantic supports the use of a default_factory for non-hashable default values, but it is not required. In the event that the default value is not hashable, Pydantic will deepcopy the default value when creating each instance of the model.

Further, I think you are confused about class and instance variables and I can imagine why:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import datetime

class DemoModel():
    ts: datetime = None  # this is a class attribute

class DemoModelPydantic(BaseModel):
    ts: datetime = None  # this is an instance attribute
```

Spot the difference? Hope it helps.